# Problema para montar query

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Não consigo montar uma query, a lógica é:

Selecionar `produtos` com `categorias` diferentes, sendo os produtos com mais pontos, assim terei um produto de mais pontos da categoria X, outro da categoria Y.

Tentei usar `DISTINCT`, algo como:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoria FROM produtos ORDER BY pontos DESC
```

O problema é que, nisso não vem as colunas que preciso ler (somente vem a `categoria`..).

O que faço para resolver este caso?

Comment: Que outras colunas você precisa ler? Se for colunas com valores diferentes o `DISTINCT` não vai funcionar

Comment: colunas como nome, preco.. a idéia é lista os produtos ordenando-os pelo maior numero de pontos, diferindo-se das categorias(quero 1 produto de cada categoria, sendo este produto de maior like). Será que devo usar algo como subqueries?

Comment: Concorda que uma categoria pode ter vários produtos nos quais possuem preços diferentes? Nesse caso você quer exibir qual preço e qual produto?

Comment: Concordo, quero selecionar produtos com categorias diferentes, sendo os produtos com mais pontos, assim terei um produto de mais pontos da categoria X, outro da categoria Y.. essa é a ideia, entendeu? Desculpe se eu não te entendi ou interpretei errado!

Comment: Qual SGBD está utilizando?

Comment: Estou utilizando o MySQL @MaiconCarraro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com as informações fornecidas nos comentários acredito que você queira isso:

```
SELECT p.categoria, MAX(p.nome) as nome, p.pontos
FROM produtos p
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT categoria, MAX(pontos) as pontos
    FROM produtos
    GROUP BY categoria
) pp ON pp.categoria = p.categoria AND pp.pontos = p.pontos
GROUP BY p.categoria, p.pontos
```

Não sei qual a coluna que mostra o nome do produto então utilizei `nome`.

O único motivo por eu ter utilizado `MAX(p.nome)` é pras situações em que um produto tiver a mesma quantidade de pontos e mesma categoria então ele pega um só.

Comment: agrupar por nome aumentou demais a lista, ja que os nomes ja eram diferentes, então o que repetiu foi as categorias.. tirei então o nome, e agrupei somente por categoria, aconteceu que listou bonito, porém o nome do produto não coincidia com os pontos no qual ele estava sendo referenciado, ou seja, nome X tinha 3 pontos, o que na verdade ele tinha 2.. Acredito que o problema foi o GROUP BY com o max(), GROUP BY não agrupou o nome de mais like.. @MaiconCarraro

Comment: Verdade, erro meu. O que dá pra fazer é um select INNER JOIN outro select pegando os max, você está a utilizar qual banco de dados? @AlexandreC.Caus

Comment: Estou utilizando o MySQL, e já te agradeço de antemão pela ajuda prestada. @MaiconCarraro

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Atualizado a resposta, da uma verificada.

Comment: Não sei se foi bruxaria.. mas deu certo, vou tentar entender o que você fez ai antes de sair aplicando, valeu @MaiconCarraro , abraços.

Comment: Esse `SELECT` dentro do `INNER JOIN` vai retornar todas categorias com suas respectivas maiores pontuaçoes, feito isso eu faço um `INNER JOIN` com a mesma tabela procurando pelo produto que contém aquela categoria e pontos.

Comment: Eu só fiz o `MAX(p.nome)` pra garantir que só vai retornar um produto por categoria, caso empatarem nos pontos :)

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o que foi explicado, fiz um modelo assim:

```
SELECT categoria, produto, pontos
from tabela a
WHERE pontos = (select max(pontos) from tabela b where a.categoria = b.categoria)
order by pontos desc
```

**exemplo:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de8e4/1

Comment: Seu `SQL` só possui um problema, quando tiver DOIS produtos com mesma `categoria` e mesmos `pontos`, dessa forma ele vai retornar os 2 produtos ao invés de 1.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Mas não é o certo? Ignorar um produto sem uma regra parece-me incorreto.

Comment: A única regra dele é ter a maioria pontuação por categoria, independente qual produto seja, mas concordo ctg que poderia ter uma regra que afetasse o `SELECT`.